# Github hooks on external repositories

Tags: github, github-api

Is it possible to make Github to send web request (hook) to my server when certain repository receives a push?

This question is related "external" repositories - which are public but I am not a member of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, setting webhooks on a repository can be done by the repository's owner only.